# How I can authenticate in codeception functional tests using Sentinel?

Tags: laravel, codeception

I am trying to test laravel app using codeception.
Inside Laravel I am using `Sentinel` for authentication.
I have a problem to authenticate user inside tests.
Non of the following examples works:

```
$I->authenticateTestUser($I);
$user = \App\User::where('email','=','test@test.com')->first();
$I->amLoggedAs($user);
$I->canSeeAuthentication();


$credentials = [
    'email'    => 'test@test.com',
    'password' => '****',
];
Sentinel::authenticate($credentials, true);
$I->canSeeAuthentication();


$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('email', $email);
$I->fillField('password', $password);
$I->click('Login');
$I->canSeeAuthentication();
```

How I can authenticate in codeception functional tests?

Comment: You can't use `Sentinel::authenticate`, the `codeception` instance is not the same as the `application`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use sentinel in the _before method :

```
private $_user;
private $_credentials;

public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    // we create a user
    $this->_credentials = [
        'last_name'  => 'Test',
        'first_name' => 'test',
        'email'      => 'test@test.fr',
        'password'   => 'password',
    ];
    $this->_user = \Sentinel::register($this->_credentials, true);

    // we log this user
    \Sentinel::authenticate($this->_credentials);
}
```

And you will be able to reuse your user or your credentials in your tests.

Comment: I have trie. Not work: '$I->canSeeAuthentication();' fails with message 'There is no authenticated user'

Comment: At the end of the `_before`method, test to add ```dd(\Sentinel::getUser())```. If you do not get `false` as result, your user is logged.